# Grant web server write permissions according to HTML filename

Tags: javascript, permissions

My site is running some flavor of Apache.

I want to allow any person on any modern hardware with JavaScript enabled to edit pages on my site via some basic `<textarea>` and `<button>` fields, if they have the right user name and password, and the right filename.

Which current combination of technologies will enable me to grant such persons write privileges for all files beginning with their username? *I am trying to avoid the use of directories for this*

I mean, is there already a package or framework that allows me to do this easily?

**Example:**

my directory:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername    142 Aug 22 12:58 about.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername   1470 Sep  7 18:42 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername   1396 Sep  7 14:08 index.html~

-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername  37553 Sep  2 12:08 laura-italy.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername  37553 Sep  2 12:08 laura-brasil.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername  37553 Sep  2 12:08 laura-usa.jpg

-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername   1512 Sep  7 07:53 tina-sylum.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername   1434 Sep  7 07:47 tina-sylum.html~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername 103403 Sep  7 07:49 tina-time.zip
```

Can I grant user `laura` with password `######` write privileges on files matching `laura-*`

and respectively, user `tina` with password `@@@@@@` write privileges on `tina-*`?

Comment: I am not sure, but given your highly narrow needs, I doubt there is a framework that is designed specifically to give you exactly this functionality. You would almost definitely have to do some code editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done in Javascript, which is client-side. There is probably no framework for this either because it's not a very robust way of designing a CMS.

All of that aside, are the users you're talking about actual *NIX users on the server?

If not, you need to be running some kind of server-side language (i.e PHP) to deal with authentication and then to handle local server files.

The basic idea is this:

1. Write the form for the login page
2. Write the authentication logic (access flat file/database)
3. After authenticating, iterate through the files in the desired directory for username matches
4. List the appropriate files
5. Write up the edit page to perform file I/O

For authentication, you might want to read up on password hashing, salting, and session handling.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to be my own keymaster. No bloated frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can save file with some anonymous name, then pass into stdin of sudo the user password like

```
echo password|sudo -u tina
echo htmledit >tina-italy.jpg
```

If tina has no right the above command will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to manage a list of users somewhere, right? And folks will have to authenticate, correct? That means you need a database. And if you're going to have folks authenticating against the database, it might make a whole lot more sense to store editable items in the database and regulate that edit access based on the authenticated user. I'm not seeing a great value added by letting the user "touch the filesystem" in this way.